# Convert a large String to data frame

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I've a large string looking like this :

```
'1 Start Date str_date B 10 C \n 2 Calculation notional cal_nt C 10 0\n 3 Calculation RATE Today cal_Rate_td C 9 R\n 10 Traea Price price 2 D 10....'
```

when the 3th field has no '_' I get an error 'ValueError: Not Enough Values to unpack(2 expected, got 1)' for splitting String to DataFrame here's my code:

```
s = '1 Start Date str_date B 10 C \n 2 Calculation notional cal_nt C 10 0\n 3 Calculation RATE Today cal_Rate_td C 9 R\n 10 Traea Price price 2 D 10'

third_fields = [e for e in s.split() if '_' in e]    

rows = []
for third_field, row in zip(third_fields, s.split('\n')): 
    current_row = []
    row = row.strip()
    first_field = re.search(r'\d+\b', row).group()
    current_row.append(first_field)
    # remove first field
    row = row[len(first_field):].strip()

    second_field, rest_of_fields = row.split(third_field)
    parsed_fields = [e.group() for e in re.finditer(r'\b[\w\d]+\b', rest_of_fields)]
    current_row.extend([second_field, third_field, *parsed_fields])

    rows.append(current_row)


pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

I found where my code bugs is in the line :

```
parsed_fields = [e.group() for e in re.finditer(r'\b[\w\d]+\b', rest_of_fields)]
```

Answer (score 0):

So by running your code without error I get this output:

```
   0                        1            2  3   4  5
0  1              Start Date      str_date  B  10  C
1  2    Calculation notional        cal_nt  C  10  0
2  3  Calculation RATE Today   cal_Rate_td  C   9  R
```

If I reproduce the code with the error I actually have it in the line before the one you suggested.

```
second_field, rest_of_fields = row.split(third_field)
```

This is because of the different output of 'third_fields' in these two situations:

```
third_fields = [e for e in s.split() if '_' in e] 
>>['str_date', 'cal_nt', 'cal_Rate_td']

third_fields = [e for e in s.split()]
>>['1', 'Start', 'Date', 'str_date', 'B', '10', 'C', '2', 'Calculation', 'notional', 'cal_nt', 'C', '10', '0', '3', 'Calculation', 'RATE', 'Today', 'cal_Rate_td', 'C', '9', 'R', '10', 'Traea', 'Price', 'price', '2', 'D', '10']
```

Which lead to an error when you try to get two elements using strip on a single string value.

If the first data frame is the results you want to achieve, you can reproduce it in this way (not the best good looking code, but you don't need regex or strange splits, and no need to worry about string without '_'):

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

s = '1 Start Date str_date B 10 C \n 2 Calculation notional cal_nt C 10 0\n 3 Calculation RATE Today cal_Rate_td C 9 R\n 10 Traea Price price 2 D 10'

rows = []
for sentence in s.split('\n'):
  sent = sentence.split()
  first = sent[0]
  rest = " ".join(str(x) for x in sent[1:-4])
  fourth_last = sent[-4]
  third_last = sent[-3]
  second_last = sent[-2]
  last = sent[-1]

  current_row = [first, rest, fourth_last, third_last, second_last, last]

  rows.append(current_row)

print(pd.DataFrame(rows))
```

Out:

```
    0                       1            2  3   4   5
0   1              Start Date     str_date  B  10   C
1   2    Calculation notional       cal_nt  C  10   0
2   3  Calculation RATE Today  cal_Rate_td  C   9   R
3  10             Traea Price        price  2   D  10
```